# Getting isMultipartContent = false while using python poster library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, multipartform-data, poster

I'm using the python poster library to try to upload a form containing including an image to a servlet.  Locally, it runs fine, but when I deploy to app engine, it doesn't recognize it as multipart content.

ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) returns false

Here's how I'm using the poster library:

```
register_openers()
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"image": open(filename)})
request = urllib2.Request(url, datagen, headers)
```

The servlet checks to make sure it is Multipart, but it fails that check.  What can I do to further debug?

Thanks,
jean

*******update*********
printing out the stack trace...here's what i get.  It complains the content type header isnull

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:885)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:349)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows (or a pedant;-), `open(filename)` is the wrong way to open a binary file and might mess things up -- use `open(filename, 'rb')`.  Apart from that, assuming of course that you continue with a `urllib2.urlopen(request)` which you've omitted, that your `import`s are correct, and that `filename` and `url` are properly set previously, then your code seems legit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Yes, I followed with urllib2.urlopen(request) and everything else is set up correctly and runs as expected when I run my appengine app locally.  When deployed, it hits the servlet, but the servlet rejects the request since I had a check to make sure it's multipart.

Comment: @jeanh, I wonder if that check is correct -- at the servlet, can you "dump" the exact byte stream it's getting (into a file, log, whatever) and peer at it to see how it differs from what's being sent?

Comment: also just checked, when running locally, request.getContentType looks fine.  After I deploy to app engine, it is null.